# if ID is missing fill the rows in another hiddenfield with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have one `Table` that is named `CustomPickedTable`, this `Table` have rows with attribute such as `<td Data-question-id="5">Example</td>` and some of the rows do not have any attribute at all. just `<td>example</td>.`

I want to do be able to sort em into different hiddenfields, these are my hiddenfields:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedCustomQuestions, new { @id = "SelectedQuestionsWithAttr" }) 
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedQuestions, new { @id = "SelectedQuestionsWithNoAttr" })
```

the code that I have right now is that all rows with attribute `"data-question-id"` gets filled to `SelectedQuestionsWithAttr` that is my hiddenfield for rows with attributes.

But I want that my Jquery code also fills those rows with no attributes gets filled to my `SelectedQuestiosnWithNoAttr` hiddenfield.

This is the code for Just filling SelectedQuestionsWithAttr hiddenfield:

```
                var selectedQuestionsWithAttr = $("#SelectedQuestionsWithAttr");
                var currentIds = new Array();

                $("#CustomPickedTable").find("td").each(function () {
                    var clickedId = $(this).attr("data-question-id");
                    currentIds.push(clickedId);
                });

                selectedQuestionsWithAttr.val(currentIds.join(","));

                $("form").submit();
            }
```

Is there any solutions that can I add to my jquery code for this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add *something* onto the `<td>` tags to be able to identify them:

```
<td id="noAttr@(Model.SelectedQuestions.IndexOf(variable))">
```

Then the jQuery would be:

```
var $qWithAttr = $("#SelectedQuestionsWithAttr");
var $qWithoutAttr = $("#SelectedQuestionsWithNoAttr");
var currentIds = new Array();
var missingIds = new Array();
$("#CustomPickedTable td[data-question-id]").each(function () {
    currentIds.push($(this).attr("data-question-id"));
 });
$("#CustomPickedTable td:not([data-question-id])").each(function () {
    missingIds.push($(this).attr("id"));
 });
 $qWithAttr.val(currentIds.join(","));
 $qWithoutAttr.val(missingIds.join(","));

 $("form").submit();
```

Comment: It should be possible to be able to just "if tables td do not have any attribute do this"

Comment: That is what the td:not([data-question-id]) selector is for. What you do within that function is up to you, but you did ask for those rows to be added into your SelectedQuestionsWithNoAttr variable and for that, they would need to be identified in some manner.